# Get newly added row in SQLite table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

In my android application, I have a SQLite database containing a table with an id column with AUTOINCREMENT. I'm using an INSERT statement to add a new row but I need to immediately access this row so I can refer to it by the ID. So does anyone know of a way to get the ID of this newly added row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SQLiteDatabase.insert` returns the id of the newly created row.

So, you would get the row like so:

```
long row = mDatabase.insert(MY_TABLE,  "id", values);
```

(above of course is just an example)

See here: [SQliteDatabase.insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

> **Returns**
>
> the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

Comment: Thanks! worked perfectly:) I was trying to use execSQL before

Comment: Bonus tip: always try and use the insert/update/delete/etc methods as opposed to executing raw SQL - you will get more out of them and they are "safer" to use :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [**`last_insert_rowid()`**](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) function

From documentation

> The last_insert_rowid() function returns the ROWID of the last row insert from the database connection which invoked the function. The last_insert_rowid() SQL function is a wrapper around the sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() C/C++ interface function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
select id from myTable where id = (select max(id) from myTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a row, the long value which is return is the id of inserted row : see

```
public long insert (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
```

Copy past link :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)